# Converting a raw input in python to a list of lists

Tags: python, regex, list, parsing

My raw input is of the format `"(1,2,3)","(3,4,5)","(6,7,8)"` and I want to convert it into a list `l = [[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]]`. I tried stripping with regex like so

```
    re.findall("(?<=\()?\d+(?=\)?)",s)
```

But the problem with this regex is that it just strips out every single number and is pretty much equivalent to

```
    re.findall("\d+", s)
```

I am looking for a simple piece of code and I don't want to go the long way by browsing through the entire input and checking if it's something I want or not.

Also could someone tell me if a raw_input in python is considered as a string by default?

Comment: In Python 2.x raw_input is a string, yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do like this

1. strip all the double quotes
2. use `ast.literal_eval` to get the tuple of tuples
3. Using list comprhension and `list` function convert the tuple of tuples to list of lists

   ```
   data = """"(1,2,3)","(3,4,5)","(6,7,8)"""""
   from ast import literal_eval
   print [list(item) for item in literal_eval(data.replace('"', ""))]
   # [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]
   ```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
s = '"(1,2,3)","(3,4,5)","(6,7,8)"'
[map(int, i[1:-1].split(',')) for i in s[1:-1].split('","')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
a = '"(1,2,3)","(3,4,5)","(6,7,8)"'
new_a = [list(eval(x)) for x in eval(a)]
```

You can also use ast.literal_eval() instead of eval() for safety !

Comment: eval is dangerous overkill.